# Angular 2 : How to load auxiliary route on application start

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am trying to load auxiliary routes when my application starts.
Although referring to [Victor Savkin's ng2 router article](http://vsavkin.tumblr.com/post/146722301646/angular-router-empty-paths-componentless-routes), [this S.O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545615/angular-2-router-auxiliary-routes-not-working-on-redirectto) and [this blog post on named router outlets](http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/#comment-82887) I didn't manage to make it work properly. I have also seen that a [possibly related issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8824) had been raised in github, and appears to be solved now.

As my code is really similar to what the named router outlet article is showing, I'll reuse [that code](https://github.com/onehungrymind/ng2-named-router-outlets).

The routes are configured as such :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'speakers', component: SpeakersComponent, children: [
    { path: 'speakersList', component: SpeakersListComponent, outlet: 'list' },
    { path: ':id', component: BioComponent, outlet: 'bio' }
  ] },
];
```

The app.component.html contains

```
<div class="app-content">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And the speakers.component.html

```
<router-outlet name="list"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="bio"></router-outlet>
```

The home.component.ts is a basic component, that enables a user to navigate to the speakers component by clicking on a button :

```
  <button md-raised-button class="md-primary"
          [routerLink]="['/speakers', {outlets: {list: ['speakersList'], bio: ['none']}}]">
          Speakers
        </button>
```

I am trying to display the speakers component when the app starts, i.e within the route's redirect. I've tried to change it to :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'speakers/speakersList', outlet: 'list', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'speakers', component: SpeakersComponent, children: [
    { path: 'speakersList', component: SpeakersListComponent, outlet: 'list' },
    { path: ':id', component: BioComponent, outlet: 'bio' }
  ] },
];
```

But it doesn't work. What is the proper way of achieving this, without using a componentless route ? I guess didn't manage to translate what is in the routerlink in the default route.

Thanks !

Edit : [Related plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/gQKpvFkXk2Ne8I1GPNAR?p=info)

Edit 2 : Appears to be an ng2 bug. You can consult the advancements being made [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12617).

Edit 3 : According to Victor Savkin: 'The issue is that we always require a primary route to be present', i.e the first child route shouldn't have a path. A fix is coming. More on the [issue here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12133)