# Angular 6 How to initialize auxiliary routes within a lazy loaded module

Tags: angular

I'm working on a big application with angular, my problem is that i'm trying to make a wizard (as in step 1: fill this form, step 2: confirm your data, etc) with auxiliary route, my problem is that i don't know how to initialize the:

```
 <router-outlet name="wizard"></router-outlet>
```

with a predefined child route.

this is my routing.module.ts

```
import { AdminOutsourceComponent } from './admin-outsource.component';
import { OutsourceComponent } from "./outsource/outsource.component";

    const routes: Routes = [


       {
        path: '',
         component: AdminOutsourceComponent,

        children: [
             {
                path: ' ',
                redirectTo:'outsourcing'
              } ,
             {
                path: 'outsourcing',
                component: OutsourceComponent,
                outlet:'wizard',
                data: {
                  title: ''
                }
              } 
        ]
      }
    ];
```

also i tried to do it like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [


         {
            path: '',
             component: AdminOutsourceComponent,

          },
         {
            path: ' ',
            redirectTo:'outsourcing'
          } ,
         {
            path: 'outsourcing',
            component: OutsourceComponent,
            outlet:'wizard'
          } 
];
```

and

```
const routes: Routes = [

       {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'wizard'
    },

      {
            path: 'wizard',
            children: [
                {
                    path: '',
                    component: AdminOutsourceComponent
                },
                {
                    path: '',
                    component: OutsourceComponent,
                    outlet: 'wizard'
                }
            ]
        }
];
```

the html template:

```
<div class="admin-wrapper">   
outsource wizard
  <router-outlet name="wizard"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I tried reading the official documentation but nothing is said about this.
So far the  `<router-outlet name="wizard"></router-outlet>` it just empty.
Here is a small application where i tried to replicate my issue.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auxiliary-routes-cbufsy?embed=1&file=app/lazy/lazy-routing/lazy-routing.module.ts

**Note:** this is an additional module that i load into my main aplication, not the main module, these submodules are lazyloaded. maybe i'm missing some configuration somewhere.

**UPDATE:** [Looks like a bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13807), not sure if it's fixed, some people still reporting problems.

Comment: both of the wizard children appear to have the same path....?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas i tried to use this solution based on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39588648/2796268

Comment: When I open your stackblitz and uncoment lines 14-18 in app.routes.ts aux route is getting initialized by ComponentAux.. so you have found the solution already? Or am I missing something in your question?

Comment: @Luckylooke read the update part in my question, people still reporting the feature that it's not working when using lazy loaded modules.

Comment: @B.J.A.A. yes, it seems to be the same proble what I have.. here is fork of your stackblitz, you can update your question https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auxiliary-routes-cbufsy?embed=1&file=app/lazy/lazy-routing/lazy-routing.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

const routes: Routes = [

```
   {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'wizard'
},

  {
        path: 'wizard',
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: AdminOutsourceComponent
            },
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'outsource',
                outlet: 'wizard'
            },
            {
                path: 'outsource',
                component: OutsourceComponent,
                outlet: 'wizard'
            }
        ]
    }
```

];