# Child component auxilory routes not redirecting

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing, angular-auxiliary-routes

I am working on an angular admin panel project. The admin login part is complete and in dash board, I have a side navigation menu, on clicking of a menu item, the corresponding component need to load in the main body div. I have my main touter-outlet placed in `app.component.html` like this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This works perfectly fine. Following is my `app-routing.module.ts`

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { LoginPageComponent } from './components/login-page/login-page.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';
import { ManageNewsComponent } from './components/manage-news/manage-news.component';
import { ManageUsersComponent } from './components/manage-users/manage-users.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  // App Routes
  {
    path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
      // Menu Routes
      { path: 'managenews', component: ManageNewsComponent, outlet: 'menu' },
      { path: 'manage_users', component: ManageUsersComponent, outlet: 'menu' }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginPageComponent },

  // otherwise redirect to home
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
```

In `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    routing,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In dashboard component html, I am trying to do this

```
<mat-toolbar color="warn">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
        <button type="button" aria-label="Toggle sidenav" mat-icon-button (click)="drawer.toggle()" color="primary">
            <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon"><i class="fa fa-bars" style="font-size:24px;color:white"></i></mat-icon>
        </button>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
    <mat-sidenav #drawer mode="side" opened role="navigation">
        <mat-nav-list>
            <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { primary: [''], menu: ['managenews'] } }]"> Manage News </a>
        </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <router-outlet name="menu"></router-outlet>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

But, clicking on the Manage news menu item, the page is not redirecting, and I am getting the following error in console:

```
core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'managenews'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'managenews'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:2469)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:2450)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:34)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:61)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:15724
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:15772
next @ core.js:17771
schedulerFn @ core.js:13515
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:196
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:134
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:77
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:13499
(anonymous) @ core.js:17321
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:150
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:17258
onHandleError @ core.js:17321
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:395
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:164
_loop_1 @ zone.js:694
api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone.js:703
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:608
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:502
invokeTask @ zone.js:1744
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1770
```

I am stuck and on going through tutorials is not able to figure out what I am doing wrong here. Please help.

Comment: this link maybe help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545615/angular-2-router-auxiliary-routes-not-working-on-redirectto

Comment: @mojtabaramezani That is redirect to, I am using auxilory routes. Both are different, right?